# Current measurement circuit

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, mosfet

[image]

I'm trying to understand the above circuit . iDE- is a ceramic sensing element and can be thought of as resistance with voltage across it , and this circuit is to measure the current through the IDE , what is the function of the Opamp in the above circuit . The output is connected to an ADC pin of a microcontroller . Is the opamp acting as a voltage buffer ?

Comment: Have you calculated its gain yet?

Comment: You need to get a better camera so we can see clearer I believe.

Comment: The gain is 1 , right?

Comment: I suspect they enable the NFET and allow enough time for a steady state to arrive, take an ADC measurement as \$V_1\$, then disable the NFET and observe \$\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}t}\$ to get \$I_1\$. By then computing \$I_X=\frac{V_1}{10\:\textrm{k}\Omega}-\frac{100\:\textrm{k}\Omega-10\:\textrm{k}\Omega}{10\:\textrm{k}\Omega}\cdot I_1\$ they can remove the bias currents and are given the actual current.

Comment: @jonk could you please elaborate on the dv/dt to get I1  part ? I couldn't quite understand it

Comment: The ADC is operated continuously, collecting a series of timed ADC values. The slope can be computed then using a simple statistical approach (well documented.) Knowing the slope and the time, the current can be clearly arrived at. Since a number of points are involved in computing \$I_1\$, noise is reduced in that value. Similarly, after steady state is reached a number of ADC values can be read for \$V_1\$ and an average taken of that, as well. So one can choose how much noise to squeeze out by choosing the number of data points involved in each measurement.

Comment: @jonk the ADC pin can only measure voltage ,right ? And the current is calculated V/R . How is slope involved in determining the current ? Sry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Just take successive adc measurements. The changes in voltage are due to current onto the capacitor. Isn't it clear how to figure the current from that?

Comment: @jonk ok thanks . And the opamp is used to remove the bias currents ? Can you please explain why an apamp is required ?

Comment: We are getting to the point where I'd need to write a long answer. If I get some time later on, I may try. But Grant me some hours.

Comment: Can you post a better picture of a larger portion of the schematics (if possible all). I am interested in the solution. I guess the MOSFET is used to add a parallel load to the heater, thus a resistance can be derived from the voltage drop, but  it needs more detailed description and schematic to understand.

Comment: @jonk that would be very helpful. Please do write one whenever you find time . Thank you.

Comment: @AkshathaVenkatesh I still do need to know details about the sensor, itself. I've assumed so far that your statement about the circuit being there to "measure the current" is accurate. But the details of that ceramic sensor (gas?) would be helpful.

Comment: @marko bursic heater ? Can you explain?

Comment: @jonk The ceramic sensor is just a PTC

Comment: The current at the point IDE- is 45/4.5Mohms = 10uA

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes hard to get into the mind of a designer. Especially, for someone like me who is merely a hobbyist with very modest practical experience in electronics.

But to my eyes the NFET must have been added for a reason. Otherwise, if it's just a current to measure then simply driving that current through a resistor would be sufficient to create a measurable voltage and that would be that.

---

Let's call the unknown current, \$I_X\$. \$R_{251}\$ and \$C_{256}\$ have a \$\tau=4.7\:\textrm{ms}\$. If you wait several \$\tau\$, the voltage at the input of the follower will settle down and the ADC's measured voltage will then be \$I_X\cdot R_{250}\$. By itself, that alone might be good enough. So why the NFET, at all? Well, obviously so they could turn it on and off. But why?

That's really the only question. And I think the answer isn't terribly complicated. The answer, I think, is found by simply asking yourself what happens when the NFET is off.

---

With \$R_{250}\$ disabled when the NFET is off, the current is mostly sunk by \$C_{256}\$ (which obviously dominates.) And assuming there are no other unknown sinks or sources, the voltage of \$C_{256}\$ will simply rise upward limited only by whatever compliance voltage sits above your PTC.

But what if you aren't sure about "other sinks or sources?" What if you want to be sure that you can measure any extraneous bias currents from the opamp follower, for example?

Well, if you assume there is another current at the opamp follower's input node, let's call it \$I_{BIAS}\$, then you do have a problem. Especially when trying to measure small currents where a bias current might be important.

Bear in mind that the maximum bias current for the LMV772 is \$250\:\textrm{pA}\$. Given that you are discussing currents on the order of \$10\:\mu\textrm{A}\$ and possibly smaller, that's a significant error value that may very well need to be nulled out!

In that case, your NFET=ON measurement will actually be measuring the ADC value \$V_X=\left(I_X+I_{BIAS}\right)\cdot R_{250}\$. How can you work out the error? Well, just turn NFET=OFF. Then the voltage will rise upward on a nearly linear ramp due to the combined currents. The slope of the voltage at the ADC will be \$\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}t}\approx \frac{I_X+I_{BIAS}}{C_{256}} \$.

So this means you can get the following two equations:

$$\begin{align*}
I_X+I_{BIAS}&= \frac{V_X}{R_{250}}\\\\
I_X+I_{BIAS}&=\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}t} C_{256}
\end{align*}$$

The value for \$\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}t}\$ can be derived by using a pair of sums of ADC values and computing the slope from a basic slope equation:

$$\frac{\textrm{d}V}{\textrm{d}t} = \frac{n\sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i \sum y_i}{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}$$

(where \$x\$ is time and \$y\$ is the ADC measurement.)

Given \$N\$ measurements, that value can be computed and the noise will be squeezed down by the \$\sqrt{N}\$ samples. So if a similar number of ADC measurements are also made for the first equation's result (and averaged, obviously, to get \$V_X=\frac{1}{N}\sum y_i\$) then there will be rough noise parity between the two sets of measurements.

With two equations and two unknowns, both can be resolved now and the truer value for \$I_X\$ determined -- without the confounding \$I_{BIAS}\$ polluting the result as much as before.

---

Once those two pairs of measurements are made, the process repeats. They turn the NFET back on and wait a bunch of \$\tau\$s until the voltage settles down again. Make some measurements to get an average value for \$V_X\$, and the turn the NFET back off, etc. Just that, over and over.

---

That's what struck me instantly when looking at the circuit, anyway. I went from "Hmm. Switch. Must be used. So what does it mean when it is OFF?" to "Oh, there is a voltage slope then. Hmm." That's all my mind did, really. I may be wrong, of course. And someone with better experience and more training (I haven't even taken so much as a DC electronics course) may certainly point out my errors here.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I just found out that the NFET is always on in my application . So the R250 is always connected to ground, but what purpose is this resistor serving ? What happens if the R251 is not present ? I know that the resistor R251 is the series resistor which is used to cause a voltage drop and that is measured by the ADC pin, but what is use of R250 ?

Comment: @AkshathaVenkatesh It, plus the following capacitance is then just acting as a filter with the \$\tau\$ I'd already mentioned, then. Reduces noise and delays the ADC input relative to the source. That's all. Too bad, as the opamp may have significant bias currents if you are right about the source current. The measurements could be made so as to remove that bias better with some software.